# Eclipse TFS check out error can't show file

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Neon with TFS plugin,

When I edit a file and try to checkout file and the file is already checkout by another user, I get the file as empty with an error :

```
The item .. is locked for checkout by .. in workspace ..
```

I can't continue to work on file, I must close window and open the file again.

Is there a way to keep working on file without getting error screen?

When I trying to lock I don't have option for [Unchanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155783(v=vs.120).aspx) - keep any existing lock .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is locked by others, you need to unlock the file then check-out to edit, otherwise it will always get the error.

You can try below ways to unlock the file:

- `tf lock /lock: none` Please see [Lock Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-command) for details:

> To use the lock command, you must have the Lock permission set to
>   Allow. Having the Unlock other user's changes permission set to Allow
>   is required to remove a lock held by another user if you do not have
>   Write permission for that user's workspace

`tf lock /lock:none /workspace:workspacename [/recursive][/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]`

- `tf undo` The undo command removes any locks on the items. See [Undo command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undo-command)

  To unlock individual files run the command below in Visual Studio Command Prompt:

  `tf undo "file_path" /workspace:workspace_name`

  e.g.:

  `tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/Abc.dll /workspace:Houst01`

  here it will unlock Abc.dll which is inside abc folder.

  To unlock the whole folder in one shot:

  `tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/* /workspace:Houst01`

  here it will unlock all files which is inside abc folder.
- You can also unlock other users file using [TFS Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) tools:

  It gives you a graphical interface to do all these commands, which makes it much easier to perform these tasks.

Comment: Thank you? Can this be applied to Eclipse?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I test at my side, it's available for Eclipse.

Comment: If file is locked I don't want to lock/unlock/undo file, just return to working with file without trying to lock

Comment: @user7294900 If you just want to edit the file without lock/unlock/undo, you can download and copy the file to another directory. Then you can edit it freely.