# TF10151: Cannot lock item is checked out by XYZ in workspace Abc

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My Scenario is this that I am unable to checkout 2 files which are locked by another user but that user is deleted.
I have tried every possible method on internet to checkout those files but no method worked.
I have also checked in the TFS DB pending changes but I did not find any entry for those files.

Can you please help me resolving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock a file from someone else in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server)

Comment: @Siddharth Rathore Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347871/eclipse-tfs-check-out-error-cant-show-file)  to force unlock the files.

Comment: @Siddharth Rathore Have you resolved your issue with the solution mentioned by nschonni?

Answer (score 2):

To remove all the locks from a deleted user, the easiest way is to delete their workspace. Even when a user is deleted, their workspaces remain.

To delete the workspace you can do:

- TFS Sidekick gives a good GUI for managing the workspaces to find the correct one to delete
  http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/
- Or using the `tf workspace /delete:Abc` https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command#deleting-a-workspace